# Querydsl search with MongoDB and DocumentReferenced (inner) collection and web support

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, querydsl, boot

In my way to explore Spring Data and MongoDB, I had the request to query a collection with its own fields. Querydsl is the best choice for what I've seen.

I have theese collections

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "subject")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Subject {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Field("subject_yupe")
    @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
    private SubjectType subjectType;
    
    // other fields
}


@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "subjecttype")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SubjectType {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Field("name")
    private String name;
}
```

This repository

```
@Repository
public interface SubjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Subject, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Subject>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QSubject> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QSubject subject) {
        bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
    }
}
```

This controller method

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<SubjectDto>> search(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Subject.class) Predicate predicate) {
    log.debug("REST request to search Subject by parameters: {}", predicate);
    // call the service that calls the repository and cast the result as List and map it
    return ResponseEntity.ok(subjectService.findAll(predicate));
}
```

When I search by one of the Subject's fields it works without any problem, I also have the correct result, following the log of Mongo query:

```
2022-12-12 21:58:31.505 DEBUG 5816 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "full_name" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : ".*\\Qgius\\E.*", "options" : "i"}}} fields: Document{{}} for class: class it.XXXXXXXXX.collections.Subject in collection: subject
```

If I try to do the same with a field of SubjectType the query is correct but the result is an empty array

```
2022-12-12 22:03:09.590 DEBUG 5816 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "subject_type.name" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : ".*\\QEntit\\E.*", "options" : "i"}}} fields: Document{{}} for class: class it.XXXXXXXXX.collections.Subject in collection: subject
```

In my opinion, since the document is linked it won't work as if it will be embedded. If i try to search for ID I have problems anyway (not that when I specity subjectType.id I only have subjectType in the query):

```
2022-12-12 22:05:25.211 DEBUG 5816 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "subject_type" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : ".*\\Q63905c45051ce75d9b060edf\\E.*", "options" : "i"}}} fields: Document{{}} for class: class it.XXXXXXXXX.collections.Subject in collection: subject
```

I'm really struggling, is there a way to search a collection for a value of its inner (not embedded) collection? Even the ID would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found an exit route: I'm using the @DBRef instead @DocumentReference and everything works fine.

I thought it was solved as requested in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4037, but latter version avoid to throw an exception, doesn't do the search